# Any way to get signed message using private key and signature?

Tags: ethereum, private-key

I have a private key and a signature, but I don't the message being signed. Can I somehow decode the signature using private key to get the message that is signed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is signed is the message hash, not the message. You cannot derive a message from its hash.